# VBA: Using a concatenated string as a command

Tags: excel, vba

How can you you use a concatenated string as a command in VBA? The following code results in the following error:

> Run-time error 424: Object required

```
Sub run()

    Dim pic As Picture
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    
    Set wks = Sheets("Counter Party Select")
    wks.Unprotect
    
    Dim company As String
    Dim sRange As String
    Dim concate As String
    Dim quote As String
    
    Dim s1 As String
    
    company = wks.Range("B3")
    
    'This vlookup pulls the correct range based on the value
    sRange = Application.VLookup(company, Sheets("Company Logos").Range("D3:E1000"), 2)
    s1 = "Company Logos"
    quote = Chr$(34) 'The character number of a quatation mark
    Concat = "Sheets(" & quote & s1 & quote & ")." & sRange

    'This results in Concat = "Sheets("Company Logos").Range("A146:A148")"
    
    Concat.Copy  'The error occurs on this line 
    
    wks.Select
    wks.Range("D2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    wks.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

How can I rewrite this code so that I can make the string an object and execute the `.Copy` command on it?

Comment: `Dim Concat As Range` and `Set Concat = WorkSheets("Company Logos").Range("A146:A148")`

Comment: You cannot use a concatenated string as a full-fledged VBA statement. You can however easily concatenate a range address. Please elaborate how you are assembling your string.

Comment: @GSerg I have a table in a sheet that has values in the first column and ranges in the second column. The procedure uses a vlookup on the first column to pull the necessary range on the second column. It then uses that range to concatenate the string

Comment: I don't see where concatenation comes from. What you have described is `Dim Concat As Range`, `Set Concat = Sheets("Company Logos").Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...))`.

Comment: @GSerg  I just added the full code so that you can see where it comes from

Comment: That is exactly what I said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849844/vba-using-a-concatenated-string-as-a-command#comment116427867_65849844). `Dim Concat As Range`, `Set Concat = Sheets(s1).Range(sRange)`, assuming `sRange` contains `"A146:A148"`. If your sheet (and therefore `sRange`) contains `"Range("A146:A148")"` in that second column, then fix it to only contain `"A146:A148"`.

Comment: @GSerg I just tried this and got ```Run-time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: @GSerg thank you just saw your next comment. I will try that

Comment: @GSerg now I have the table on the sheet containing this syntax ```"A146:A148"``` and I'm getting this error ```Run-time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error```

Comment: You have a `!` instead of the column name, and I assume you have left the quotes around the address, those need to go to.

Comment: @GSerg I'm sorry, I corrected that syntax. I have the range correctly specified on the table and still receiving the same error ```"A146:A148"```

Comment: @GSerg yes the quotes are included in the cells in the table

Comment: So please remove them too.

Comment: @GSerg awesome thank you that works now! Would you like to formally add an answer so that you can receive credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a concatenated string as a full-fledged VBA statement. You can however easily concatenate a range address.

You cannot do that straight away because you have made your life more complicated by storing wrong data:

> ```
> 'This results in Concat = "Sheets("Company Logos").Range("A146:A148")"
> ```

You should not store the literal text `Range("A146:A148")` in that second column that you `VLookup`. You should only store the address itself, `A146:A148`, as text.

Fix the data on the sheet accordingly, and it will work as expected:

```vb
Dim Concat As Range
Set Concat = Sheets(s1).Range(sRange)
```